# LDF-files and simple recovery model

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-to-SQL (dbml) to work with dbf-database (LocalDB). This will be a local database for my application to hold some data.

I've noticed there are `*.ldf` and `*_log.ldf` files, which are quite big. While I assume, what some administration could be done with sql tools, I'd rather prefer not to require that in most cases. I already solve following problems: creating, attaching, detaching and file-based manipulations with mdf-file for a sort of primitive installation/backup (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25932031/1997232)).

Is it possible to get rid of ldf-files without putting too much effort? Like deleting them after detaching?

After finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826789/1997232) question, I've come to idea, what maybe it is possible to set *simple recovery model* in my dbml? This solution would be more optimal (if possible), as big ldf-files will not even be created.

How do I set *simple recovery model* when using dbml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Not really directly in DBML.

But you can execute SQL through Linq.

The statement to use is:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET RECOVERY [FULL | BULK_LOGGED | SIMPLE]
```

So in Linq it would be something like

```
db.ExecuteCommand("ALTER ... ");
```

Comment: Didn't know it is that simple, thanks. Btw, setting simple mode doesn't decrease ldf-file size (maybe it already was simple?). So currently I am simple deleting all ldf-files after detaching database. Looks harmless so far.